# bootstrap-datepicker :- startDate not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

bootstrap-datepicker included in my project to implement the datepicker for DateOfBirth purpose.
Target is : Start date should be '01/01/1950'
format: mm/dd/yyyy.

I done with the following code but result is un-achieved.

 My code is as below:

```
<input placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="dob" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="patient.dateOfBirth" ng-required="true" />
```

**JS**

```
var dob = $('#dob').datepicker({
        startDate: '01/01/1950',
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        startView : 'decade',
        onRender: function (rdate) {
            return (rdate.valueOf() >= startDate.valueOf()) && (rdate.valueOf() < now.valueOf()) ? '' : 'disabled';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        dob.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'result is un-achieved'? specify the problem.

Comment: Which datepicker do you use ? eyecon ? eternicode ?

Comment: @shaunakde start date is still current date in datepicker.

Comment: @TheLittlePig : eyecon datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with AngularJS as I can tell, your problem lies in `ng-model`. To define a start date you have to set `patient.dateOfBirth` to that in order for AngularJS to properly map it:

```
$scope.patient.dateOfBirth = new Date(1950, 01, 01);
```

However, you can opt for other twitter bootstrap datetime directives that work more nicely with AngularJS. Case in point: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker